# Handling a belongs_to relation with backbone.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I am kind of new with backbone.js and i am struggling with fetching a collection with a belong_to relation.

I would like to fetch a list of users (users/ GET) and i would like to display them all but with a belongs_to association.

For example to display the company name of the user. Somebody knows a solution?

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 with CouchDB

## users controller

```
def index
  User.all
end
```

## Backbone collection

```
class UserCollection extends Backbone.Collection

  url: ->
    app.routes.users_url

  model: User
```

## Backbone model

```
class User extends Backbone.Model

  idAttribute: '_id'

  defaults: {
    "email": null
    "mobile": null
    "loc": null
  }

  url: ->
    app.routes.users_url + '/' + (@id || '')
```

I would like to show the company name like this...

```
%script{:id => "user-resource-template", :type => "text/template"}
  %td= check_box_tag "select", 1, false, :class => "checkbox", "data-id" => raw("<%= _id %>")
  %td <%= name %>
  %td <%= email %>
  %td <%= company.name %>
```

Comment: so what is not working correctly?

Comment: Well the belongs to relation isnt working, which is logic ofcourse because the model doesnt have anything of a relation. So I dont know how to print company.name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Backbone.js doesn't seem to support relations, as there is no mention of them in the [official documentation](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model).

All is not lost, though, there are some Backbone plugins that add support for relations, such as [Backbone-relational](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational) or [ligament.js](https://github.com/dbrady/ligament.js). I haven't tested them, but Backbone-relational seems pretty active.

**Update**

To lazy-load collections and prevent one fetch per relation, see the `fetchRelated` method in [Backbone.RelationalModel](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational#backbone-relationalmodel):

> Fetch models from the server that were referenced in the model's
>   attributes, but have not been found/created yet. This can be used
>   specifically for lazy-loading scenarios.
>
> By default, a separate request will be fired for each additional model
>   that is to be fetched from the server. However, if your server/API
>   supports it, you can fetch the set of models in one request by
>   specifying a collectionType for the relation you call fetchRelated on.
>   The collectionType should have an overridden
>   url(models) method that allows it to construct a url
>   for an array of models. See the example at the top of
>   [Backbone.Relation options](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational#backbone-relation) or [Backbone-tastypie](https://github.com/PaulUithol/backbone-tastypie/blob/master/backbone_tastypie/static/js/backbone-tastypie.js#L79) for an example.

Comment: Yes that looks nice but that means i have to do a request for every row in the collection. So that means 20 request on a normal users index action.

Comment: Updated my answer, is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks for this. This is indeed the right answer. I am gonna do it another way because of some reasons with the server but this is the right answer. Thanks!